# I can scroll faster than images load. How to pre-load?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make an infinite scrollable list, but the problem I am having is that I can easily scroll faster than the new images load. I believe that the images are not actually loaded until they are displayed on screen. I want images to load in the background before I scroll so I do not see am empty box. How can I accomplish that?

post_summary.dart:

```
class PostSummary {
  PostSummary({
    required this.id,
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.width,
    required this.height,
  });

  factory PostSummary.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PostSummary(
        id: json['id'],
        imageUrl: json['url'],
        width: json['width'],
        height: json['height'],
      );

  final String id;
  final String imageUrl;
  final int width;
  final int height;
}
```

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:very_good_infinite_list/very_good_infinite_list.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

import 'post_summary.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Simple Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Simple Example')),
        body: const Feed(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Feed extends StatefulWidget {
  const Feed({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  FeedState createState() => FeedState();
}

class FeedState extends State<Feed> {
  List<PostSummary> _items = [];
  var _isLoading = false;

  void fetchData() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    const headers = {
      'x-api-key':
          'SECRET',
    };

    final Uri catApiUri =
        Uri.parse('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?limit=10&page=1');

    final response = await http.get(catApiUri, headers: headers);
    List<PostSummary> parsedResponse = (jsonDecode(response.body) as List)
        .map((data) => PostSummary.fromJson(data))
        .toList();

    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      print(
          'Failed to fetch data from the API with status code: ${response.statusCode}');
    }

    if (!mounted) {
      return;
    }

    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
      _items = [..._items, ...parsedResponse];
      print(_items.length);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InfiniteList(
      itemCount: _items.length,
      isLoading: _isLoading,
      onFetchData: fetchData,
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const SizedBox(
          height:
              20.0), // Use a SizedBox instead of Divider for cleaner separation
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              // Image taking the full width of the container
              ClipRRect(
                  // Use ClipRRect for a rounded corner on the image
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                  child: CachedNetworkImage(
                    imageUrl: _items[index].imageUrl,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 300.0,
                    errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                        const Icon(Icons.error),
                  )),
              const SizedBox(
                  height:
                      10.0), // Use a SizedBox for a cleaner space management
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  // Display the ID and potentially other data here
                  Text(
                    'ID: ${_items[index].id}',
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 16.0, // Slightly increased font size
                    ),
                  ),
                  // ... Add other widgets if needed
                ], // Align the text to the start
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I am learning Flutter so any feedback is appreciated! Thank you for your help :)

Comment: If you do not want to show an empty box, same way you are using the errorWidget, you can use the placeholder parameter. This will let you display something while images are being loaded. Try adding something like this:

placeholder: (context,url) => CircularProgressIndicator(). Know that you can replace the CircularProgressIndicator with any widget of your desire... this is just an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precache images before updating state using `precacheImage` function.

```dart
Future<void> precacheImages(List<PostSummary> items) async {
  for (var item in items) {
    await precacheImage(CachedNetworkImageProvider(item.imageUrl), context);
  }
}

void fetchData() async {
  setState(() {
    _isLoading = true;
  });

  const headers = {
    'x-api-key': 'SECRET',
  };

  final Uri catApiUri =
  Uri.parse('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?limit=10&page=1');

  final response = await http.get(catApiUri, headers: headers);
  List<PostSummary> parsedResponse = (jsonDecode(response.body) as List)
      .map((data) => PostSummary.fromJson(data))
      .toList();

  if (!mounted) {
    return;
  }
  
  // precache here
  await precacheImages(parsedResponse);

  setState(() {
    _isLoading = false;
    _items = [..._items, ...parsedResponse];
  });
}
```